# How to prove that the limit of a sequence is greater or equal to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For a sequence $\;\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$ for which $a_n\ge0$, $∀n ∈ \mathbb{N}+$ where $\;\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$ converges to $l$, I want to prove that $l\ge0$. I know that this is an obvious proposition, but I'm struggling with coming up with an appropriate proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The title of your question is greater, and in the question it is greater than *or equal to*.

Comment: Assume $l<0$ and take $\epsilon=-\frac{l}{2}$.

Comment: @Arthur I don't think the OP meant the sequence is an integer one, but rather the second time he forgot to subindex that. I think it shoud be $\;(An)_{n\in\Bbb N=}\;$ , though it would probably better to denote $\;\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset\Bbb R\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the limit $l$ is such that
$l<0$.

let $\epsilon=-\frac{l}{2}>0$

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}A_n=l \implies$$

$\exists N \in \mathbb N :$
$\forall n\geq N$

$$l-\epsilon<A_n<l+\epsilon \implies$$

$$\forall n\geq N  \; \; A_n<\frac{l}{2}<0$$

and this is the contradiction with $A_n\geq0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

so $l\geq 0$

Comment: Something is wrong.the question   has been asked after the answer of @Henry W. !!!!! ?????

Answer (score 1):

Try proof by contrapositive. Let $l < 0$ and find an $n$ such that $A_n < 0$. (Hint: Let $\epsilon = -l$)